# How to get value of variable from curl in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working on two system.In which asterisk runs on one system-1.I want to run command in asterisk and get result back in system-2.I make curl request like below.How to get value back on system2?`enter code here`

```
  exec('asterisk -rx "sip show peers"',$sip);

  $POST_DATA = array(
          'filename'=>$sip,
          );

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'http://192.168.50.138/test.php');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);


  ?>
```

Comment: `print_r($response);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

in your code. curl_exec should already returns the content of the page instead of a BOOL.

This is a snippet of a library I use. As pointed out this might not be needed but it helped me out once...

```
//The content - if true, will not download the contents
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
```

Also it seems to have some bugs related to CURLOPT_NOBODY (which might explain why you have this issue):

- http://osdir.com/ml/web.curl.general/2005-07/msg00073.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-03/0072.html